# The random seeming value I get when assigning an array in a vector and accessing its adress

Tags: c++

I have a question and an assumption.

## My Program Set Up:

I am playing around in c++ for some time now and tried to create a vector

```
std::vector<int*> loadedVectors;
```

which holds the address to an integer, which is the first adress to an array of size 3.
In the following code block are three functions.

The first "pOLoadedVectors" prints out all vectors in the "std::vector<*int> loadedVectors" to the console.
The second and third function essentially "do the same" but in a different way.

The **second** function which takes in an **int array[3]** gets the pointer to the first element of the array and stores that in the **loadedVectors** "std::vector".

The **third** function takes in **three integers x,y and z** and creates an **array[3]** with those values respectively in the first, second and third position. Then gets the pointer to the first element and puts that in the **loadedVectors** "std::vector".

```
void pOLoadedVectors(){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < loadedVectors.size(); i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                std::cout << *(loadedVectors.at(i) + j) << std::endl;
            }

        }
    };

    size_t createVector(int val[dimensions]){
        int *push = val;
        loadedVectors.push_back(push);
        return loadedVectors.size() - 1;
    }

    size_t createVector(int x, int y, int z){
        int p[dimensions] = {x * factorToFloat,y * factorToFloat,z * factorToFloat};
        int *push = p;
        loadedVectors.push_back(push);
        return loadedVectors.size() - 1;
    }
```

These three functions are in the namespace I called "engine".

If I now run the following main function

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    using namespace engine;
    int a[3] = {1,10,100};
    createVector(a);
    createVector(1,0,0);
    pOLoadedVectors();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following result.

```
1
10
100
22029
1
0
```

The numbers "1", "10" and "100" are from the **second** function.
The numbers "22029", "1" and "0" are from the **third** function.

## My Question:

I have heard that as soon as the program goes out of scope and object will be deleted.
In my understanding, the array which is created in the **third** function should be deleted and freed up for other use after the program goes out of scope.
Now at least the first print out from the **third** function suggests this. But it seems that the second value is the "x"-input of the **third** function. And the third outputted value is the "y" input of the **third** function.

Now after further investigation I find out that the printed out 1 and 0 are always there for some reason.

But am I correct in assuming that those values are not correct because the array is being deleted?

Comment: Try calling `createVector(int, int, int)` twice in a row and see what happens.

Comment: Also, how are `22029`, `1`, and `0` from the third function? The values should be `floor(factorToFloat), 0, 0`.

Comment: "should be deleted and freed up for other use after the program goes out of scope" - this is mostly true, but it really doesn't need to be like this. I think it's not a good idea to rely on this.

Comment: *I have heard that as soon as the program goes out of scope and object will be deleted.* the lifetimes of objects vary depending on how and where they are allocated. [See the section on Storage duration linked here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: At the end of the `createVector(int x, int y, int z)` function, the array `p` goes out of scope, and is therefore destroyed. Accessing it after this point is UB, which means **anything** is possible. You may get the values of `x` and `y` from the other function. You may get `0` and `1` randomly. You may format your hard drive.